# Why will .exe created with cx_Freeze not run? It tells me: python33.dll is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

I have successfully frozen my Python 3.3 application using cx_Freeze into an .exe and it runs fine until I move the enclosing folder which contains image files and suchlike to another folder or try on another (Windows) computer and run it. A Windows error then says:

```
The application has failed to start because the extension python33.dll was not found.
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Probably because the .exe depends on `python33.dll`?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yeah, that's what I assumed and the python33.dll file is in the folder alongside the exe and all, yet it won't run.

Comment: [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingStandaloneExecutables) might be helpful..  It mentions some steps to remove hard coded path information from the libraries.

Comment: @Mike What is it you speak of?

Comment: Check out the section on **chrpath**.

Comment: @Mike I'm on Windows, so not sure if this applies to me. Also, I don't have wPython installed and would prefer to keep the application file size down and just get the thing able to be downloaded by my Pythonless friends! Any other options?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I think these programs just kinda wrap your program in a launcher, but it still requires the Python runtime underneath.  I'm not sure if there's anything that will convert a Python script into a totally self-contained EXE with zero dependencies.

Comment: That's weird. You definitely shouldn't need this chrpath thing. To be clear, you can run the exe in the folder where you've frozen it? But if you move the whole folder on the same computer, it stops working?

Comment: @Thomas No worries, all I needed was to extract the folder. *facepalm*